# Sencha Touch 2.3 mapListeners example

Tags: google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch

Sencha Touch 2.3.0 introduced with native google maps events listeners via *mapListeners* option. I need some example of attaching click event to the marker (via this particular option, I know how to do it via google maps api).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you cannot attach event listener to the marker via mapListeners.

Line 287 of the touch-2.3.0/src/Map.js is:

```
handle = event.addListener(map, eventType, Ext.bind(callbackFn, callbackFn));
```

Where:

1. event is gm.event (google.maps.event), line 263;
2. map is this.getMap() (the map object itself), line 258;
3. eventType is one of the keys of mapListeners object, line 267;
4. callbackFn is your callback, line 278

Thus, mapListeners are limited to the listeners of the **map**:

- bounds_changed
- center_changed
- click **(fired when the user clicks on the map, but not when they click on a marker or infowindow)**
- dblclick
- drag
- dragend
- dragstart
- heading_changed
- idle
- maptypeid_changed
- mousemove
- mouseout
- mouseover
- projection_changed
- resize
- rightclick
- tilesloaded
- tilt_changed
- zoom_changed